# Codeigniter--How do store info? (noob)

Tags: codeigniter

I'm building my first real CI app.  I have to build a survey system--If the specifics are important, I'll elaborate.

What is the best way to post the info to the db from the user? In a single row, comma separated?  I'm a noob here, so detail would be appreciated! :)

**I should add: the user needs to have the ability to try multiple times for the test and have each test's score charted. Payment is required to take each test.**

Here's where I'm at.  This code works, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do things.

```
$this->db->select('credits')->from('be_user_profiles')->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('id'));
$query = $this->db->get();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->credits;
}
```

What about this?

Comment: Definitely more info is necessary, what kind of info are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's more like a code organization / code structure question than a problem.

You can fetch your input data "by hand" or use Active Record CI library to do that (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#insert)

If CI has ORM implemented, the job should be even easier than this.

Just create a controller and check the input data on it (or inside the model) and create a model to apply the necessary cleanups, data verification and proper data assign to one or mode tables and you're set.

**edit :** more elegant than the example you've showed would be with ORM, but I'm not sure CI has that implemented yet.

Comment: Yea, CI has a library for ORM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the data is structured, but your best bet would be to have a survey table, and store the answer to each question in a different column.

From an MVC point of view, you would have a form in a view, have the controller pass the data from that form the model when it is submitted, then have the model clean the data and insert it into the database.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  What do you mean "clean the data"? :)

Comment: using function like mysql_real_escape_string() and such to make sure the data is safe. NEVER trust user input.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  Is this synonymous with validation?